# How can you make certain parts of your website not appear on search engine results?

Tags: web, search-engine

How can you make certain parts of your website not appear on search engine results?

Will a password protected directory not appear on search engine results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website top level directory place robots.txt file with the following content.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: Password-folder-name
```

For more info ,see this [link](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

> Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion Protocol.